# Unsubscribe from AsyncSubject?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm using `AsyncSubject` to wait for some config from backend, but I already know the data that config should be applied to. I want to use subscription on this AsyncSubject as a delay prior real processing. **Do I need to unsubscribe in that case?**

https://rxviz.com/v/WJxG0RqO

```
const { AsyncSubject } = Rx
const { map } = RxOperators

class Smth {
  constructor(options$) {
    this.options$ = options$
    this.sum = 0
  }

  append(val) {
    this.options$.subscribe(opts => {
      this.sum += parseInt(val, opts.base)
      // Do I need to unsubscribe from AsyncSubject?
    })
  }

  compute() {
    return this.options$.pipe(
      map(() => this.sum)
    )
  }
}

function run() {
  var opts$ = new AsyncSubject()
  setTimeout(() => { // Opts will be provided later - emulate fetch request
    opts$.next({ base: 7 })
    opts$.complete()
  }, 1000)

  var smth = new Smth(opts$)
  smth.append("15") // But the arguments are already known
  smth.append("5")
  smth.append("66")
  smth.append("0")

  return smth.compute()
}

run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to unsubscribe if you are sure that the observable you are subscribed to completes: it will unsubscribe automatically in this case